# gRPC & HTTP servers on GKE Ingress failing healthcheck for gRPC backend

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-health-check

I want to deploy a gRPC + HTTP servers on GKE with HTTP/2 and mutual TLS. My deployment have both a readiness probe and liveness probe with custom path. I expose both the gRPC and HTTP servers via an Ingress.

deployment's probes and exposed ports:

```
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /_ah/health
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /_ah/health
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
    name: grpc-gke
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8443
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 50052
      protocol: TCP
```

NodePort service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpc-gke-nodeport
  labels:
    app: grpc-gke
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"grpc":"HTTP2","http":"HTTP2"}'
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/app-protocols: '{"grpc":"HTTP2", "http": "HTTP2"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    port: 50052
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 50052
  - name: http
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: grpc-gke
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grpc-gke-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "grpc-gke-ip"
  labels:
    app: grpc-gke
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /_ah/*
        backend:
          serviceName: grpc-gke-nodeport
          servicePort: 443
  backend:
    serviceName: grpc-gke-nodeport
    servicePort: 50052
```

The pod does exist, and has a "green" status, before creating the liveness and readiness probes. I see regular logs on my server that both the `/_ah/live` and `/_ah/ready` are called by the kube-probe and the server responds with the `200` response.

I use a Google managed TLS certificate on the load balancer (LB). My HTTP server creates a self-signed certificate -- inspired by [this blog](https://benguild.com/2018/11/11/quickstart-golang-kubernetes-grpc-tls-lets-encrypt/).

I create the Ingress after I start seeing the probes' logs. After that it creates an LB with two backends, one for the HTTP and one for the gRPC. The HTTP backend's health checks are OK and the HTTP server is accessible from the Internet. The gRPC backend's health check fails thus the LB does not route the gRPC protocol and I receive the `502` error response.

This is with GKE master 1.12.7-gke.10. I also tried newer 1.13 and older 1.11 masters. The cluster has HTTP load balancing enabled and VPC-native enabled. There are firewall rules to allow access from LB to my pods (I even tried to allow all ports from all IP addresses). Delaying the probes does not help either.

Funny thing is that I deployed nearly the same setup, just the server's Docker image is different, couple of months ago and it is running without any issues. I can even deploy new Docker images of the server and everything is great. I cannot find any difference between these two.

There is one another issue, the Ingress is stuck on the "Creating Ingress" state for days. It never finishes and never sees the LB. The Ingress' LB never has a front-end and I always have to manually add an HTTP/2 front-end with a static IP and Google managed TLS certificate. This should be happening only for cluster which were created without "HTTP load balancing", but it happens in my case every time for all my "HTTP load balancing enabled" clusters. The working deployment is in this state for months already.

Any ideas why the gRPC backend's health check could be failing even though I see logs that the readiness and liveness endpoints are called by kube-probe?

**EDIT:**

`describe svc grpc-gke-nodeport`

```
Name:                     grpc-gke-nodeport
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=grpc-gke
Annotations:              cloud.google.com/app-protocols: {"grpc":"HTTP2","http":"HTTP2"}
                        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"cloud.google.com/app-protocols":"{\"grpc\":\"HTTP2\",\"http\":\"HTTP2\"}",...
                        service.alpha.kubernetes.io/app-protocols: {"grpc":"HTTP2", "http": "HTTP2"}
Selector:                 app=grpc-gke
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.4.8.188
Port:                     grpc  50052/TCP
TargetPort:               50052/TCP
NodePort:                 grpc  32148/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.0.25:50052
Port:                     http  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30863/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.0.25:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

and the health check for the gRPC backend is an HTTP/2 GET using path `/` on port `32148`. Its description is "Default kubernetes L7 Loadbalancing health check." where as the description of the HTTP's back-end health check is "Kubernetes L7 health check generated with readiness probe settings.". Thus the health check for the gRPC back-end is not created from the readiness probe.

Editing the health check to point to port `30863` an changing the path to readiness probe fixes the issue.

Comment: I'm curious if this is maybe a limitation of the LB health check. modifying the gRPC HC to match that of the HTTP one should def work since we know that path is responding. I'll see if I can find anything

Comment: I also noticed that your readiness and liveness probes both check port 8443, so not gRPC.

Comment: @PatrickW I need both probes to check port 8443, because I am unaware of returning an HTTP/2 response on port where the gRPC server is listening. I have basically an HTTP server listening on 8443 in the same binary as the gRPC server and it responds to different health checks as needed. But the LB HC for the gRPC backend ignores the readiness probe settings.

Comment: ok so that is the issue, the HC does not work against the gRCP port. This is why using the LB HC against port 32148 fails. In the above config, only port  30863 will result in a healthy backend. HTTP/2 is still in beta and work is being done to get gRPC to work fully.

Comment: @PatrickW I thought that the LB HC should be set to the readiness probe's settings. I am using Ingress which creates an LB. ...funny thing is that we have deployed a similar setup (months ago, but has weekly updates) and the "bad" LB HC works. It is set to the `/` and NodePort's port of the gRPC backend. Weird beta vesions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the health check to point to the readiness probe's path and changed the port to the one of the HTTP back-end fixed this issue (look for the port in the HTTP back-end's health check. it is the NodePort's.). It runs know without any issues.

Using the same health check for the gRPC back-end as for the HTTP back-end did not work, it was reset back to its own health check. Even deleting the gRPC back-end's health check did not help, it was recreated. Only editing it to use a different port and path has helped.

Comment: Can you provide way more details please? I have a go service runing a GRPC server on 8080 and a gRPC Gateway (mirror REST of my gRPC protobuf definition) on 8081. I am currently working on Ingress (GKE) and I am a bit stuck regarding the access to my gRPC endpoint

Comment: @Emixam23 Check this article for more details about setting up a gRPC + HTTP service in GKE https://medium.com/mintensive/go-grpc-server-with-mutual-tls-on-gke-9645389a2224

Comment: I've been working on it all day, and as the 2 past weeks, same issue.. even if I implement the health check part and it actually returns OK, still doesn't work.. I've setup a public repo as I am working with other people on it: https://github.com/Emixam23/GKE-gRPC-Service-Ingress To make it even easier, I removed the Gateway part (gRPC Rest Gateway) so now, I only have the gRPC backend running

Answer (score 1):

GKE ingress just recently started supporting full gRPC support in beta (whereas HTTP2 ro HTTP1.1 conversion was used in the past). To use gRCP though, you need to add an annotation to the ingress "cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"http2-service":"HTTP2"}'".
[Refer to this how-to doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-http2) for more detais.

Comment: I use the HTTP2 annotation in the Ingress and in the old deployment it works and in this one it does not.

Comment: Can you verify that the health check being used for the gRPC backend matches your readiness probe? It's possible the LB health check was created incorrectly or it is using a previously created health check.

Comment: It does not match the readiness probe. It never matched it, even in the working gRPC service deployed months ago. It is always pointing on the `/` and uses the port of the gRPC service. The health check for the HTTP backend uses the readiness probe. Editing the health check to point to the readiness probe's path and changed the port to the one of the HTTP backend fixes this issue. But editing of the auto-generated health checks (from Ingress) is not recommended... I am testing this edited health check since Friday morning and it is still working...

Comment: they won't match exactly, the readiness probe will be 443, where as the HC of your lB should be the nodeport (3xxxx) and it should use the nodeport of the backend service. It should also be set to use HTTPS rather than http. Can you update your post with the kubectl describe svc grpc-gke-nodeport and the definition of your healthcheck

Comment: The LB's health check used the port of NodePort'ss service for the gRPC service (in this case 32148) instead of the HTTP ones. I switched to the NodePort's port for the HTTP 30863 and changed the path. All my health checks use HTTP/2. I have updated the question with the info you asked for. There is one funny pattern, the LB makes a burst of three health check requests within one second every time.

Comment: the HC burst isn't overly surprising, you'll get at least 1 HC per node even if you only have a single pod being checked. And on top of that, you will frequently see other requests as well since Googlewill send HC from multiple sources to ensure redundancy

Comment: The HC burst is happening in a single node cluster. I have set different paths for readiness probe, liveness probe and for the LB HC. readines and liveness paths are called once and LB HC is called three times.

Comment: yeah the readiness and liveness probes are sent from the kubelet. The HC is sent from the Google managed Load Balancers. Multiple requests are sent at the same time per node to ensure redundancy. This is expected